# How to call a Lua method on startup in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm using Lua with NGINX. My code has a lua method called "rabbitmq.createExchange". I want to call this method, when nginx server starts.

I tried following code, but i failed with error "content_by_lua_block directive is not allowed here". Any solutions?

> http {
>
> ```
> lua_package_path '/app/nginx/src/?.lua;;';
>
> server {
>  listen 4000;
>  include 'src/proj1.conf';
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> content_by_lua_block {
>   local rabbitmq = require 'src/rabbitmq.lua';
>   rabbitmq.createExchange("nginx", "topic");
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want [`init_by_lua_block`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#init_by_lua_block) - the `content_by_lua_block` directive is specifically for responding to a particular `location`, whereas the `init_` version is for startup:

> ### init_by_lua_block
>
> **syntax:** *init_by_lua_block { lua-script }*
>
> **context:** *http*
>
> **phase:** *loading-config*
>
> Similar to the `init_by_lua` directive except that this
>   directive inlines the Lua source directly inside a pair of curly
>   braces (`{}`) instead of in an NGINX string literal (which requires
>   special character escaping).
>
> For instance,
>
> ```
>  init_by_lua_block {
>      print("I need no extra escaping here, for example: \r\nblah")  }
> ```

(From the `init_by_lua` section, *"Runs the Lua code [...] on the global Lua VM level when the Nginx master process (if any) is loading the Nginx config file."*)